# Чем объяснить обособление (см.)?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

> За небольшую плату здесь позволяют спуститься на уровень Рима первого
>   века, который расположен метров на десять ниже современного. **Там, в
>   полутьме,** можно расслышать тихий плеск и разглядеть наполненный
>   бассейн античной виллы, в который ведут мраморные ступени.

Если *можно* не править, *нужно* не править.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваших примерах обособлены уточняющие обстоятельства места. Там (где?), (где именно?) в  полутьме, можно расслышать <...>.

Ср. другие примеры:  **Там, ниже,** мох тощий, кустарник седой (П.); Внизу, **в тени,** шумел Дунай (Тютч.);

Comment: "Там, ниже" - два обстоятельства МЕСТА. А у меня - глубина и освещение... А вот "низ, тень" уже вдохновляют!

Comment: Галина, причем здесь глубина и освещение? Имеется в виду само место , где  полутьма.  Если исходить из этого, то не надо обособлять:  Внизу, в тени...

Comment: Нельзя сказать: в чем?

Comment: Если изменить предложение: "Там, при слабом освещении, можно расслышать тихий плеск и разглядеть наполненный бассейн античной виллы, в который ведут мраморные ступени." - тогда как?

Comment: Сержу: Да я бы и "внизу в тени" никаких запятых не плодила, но это ж текст поэтический - у него свои вольности... М_Г: "Там, при слабом освещении, можно расслышать..." - знаки остаются авторскими, нерегламентированными!

Comment: @Галина, пример взят из справочника Розенталя, а там ни о каких вольностях не говорится.  Надо учитывать смысловую сторону.

Comment: @ М_Г,  в вашем примере оборот "при слабом освещении" является  обособленном обстоятельством. Обособление таких обстоятельств  является факультативным.

Comment: Ладно, факультативные знаки - это всё же не своеволие. Оставляем как есть, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Там, **в полутьме,** можно расслышать тихий плеск и разглядеть наполненный бассейн античной виллы, в который ведут мраморные ступени.

Обстоятельство сообщает **дополнительные сведения**  о слабой освещенности  данного места, но при этом  не уточняет его координаты. Обособление в данном случае связано **не с семантикой, а с позицией обстоятельства**, в которой его просто нельзя не обособить.

Сравнить: Там можно расслышать тихий плеск и **в полутьме** разглядеть наполненный бассейн античной виллы, в который ведут мраморные ступени.

Comment: Почему же не уточняет? Там (где?),  (где именно?)в полутьме. Какие дополнительные сведения сообщаются о полутьме? Здесь уточняются обстоятельства места.

Comment: А по-моему, "в полутьме" уточняет не место, а освещенность: "Там (а там вы будете в полутьме) можно расслышать тихий плеск и разглядеть...". Место и так ясно: "уровень Рима первого века, который расположен метров на десять ниже современного."

Comment: М_Г@,какое именно освещение?

Answer (score 0):

В чем сомнение? Я бы начал сомневаться, если бы на первом месте стояло "разглядеть" (в полутьме разглядеть), а не "расслышать". Но в Вашем  предложении "в полутьме" - приложение (это кажется мне очевидным), оно обособляется.

Comment: Почему обособляется?! "Там" (десятью метрами ниже) само по себе, а степень освещённости сама по себе...